How disable the print button in web browser control in wpf vb.net?
I successfully rendered the pdf using webBrowser.navigate("some.pdf"). Is it possible to disable the print button and shortcut keys for printing?
I tried webBrowser.NavigateToString but I cannot make it work. I hope someone can help me.

You should use WebView2 class. It uses a modern Chromium based engine. WebBrowser uses the antique Internet Explorer. As both classes essentially host an Internet Explorer or Edge browser instance you can't access any bottoms as they are part of the hosted browser. Those are not native WPF controls.

Since I can't disable the print button in web browser control. I disable all the controls using this line of code
CType(web, System.Windows.Forms.Control).Enabled = False

and add an event for previewkeydown when detect ctrl + p.
